# Iterate over list of values

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a table with the following columns: `column_a`, `column_b`, and `column_c`. These columns are counts of something and I want to add two to each column, creating new columns `column_a_new`, `column_b_new`, and `column_c_new`.

How can I iterate over an arbitrary list of values in a macro statement? I know this would be easy if I had a sequence of integers, with something like `%do i=0 %to &n.`...

Comment: Please show what you've attempted with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are designed for this, though you need to handle the naming then. There are multiple easy ways of doing this.

```
data new;
   set old;

   array _input(*) column_a column_b column_c;
   array _output(*) column_a_new column_b_new column_c_new;

   do i=1 to dim(_input);
        _output(i) = input(i) + 2; *consider how missing values will be handled;
   end;
run;
```

To create the variable lists automatically you can use the SASHELP.VCOLUMN data set or you can use PROC CONTENTS and dynamically generate the variable lists.
Depending on how the original list is specified there are many ways to generate the list with _new at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to load the column names into a macro variable and do some iteration through those values. If that is the case, `%scan` is your friend in this case.

```
/* Assuming items are separated by a space */
%let list_to_iterate = %str(item1 item2 item3 item4);

%let ii = 1;
%do %while (%scan(&list_to_iterate , &ii, %str( )) NE %str());
      %let this_item = %scan(&list_to_iterate , &ii, %str( ));

      /* Do what you have to do with &this_item here */

      %let ii = %eval(&ii + 1);

%end;
```

However there are simpler ways to achieve what you are really describing isn't it? Just do something like `column_a_new = column_a + 1;`? Probably there is more to it than this since you are looking for a macro based soltuion.

Answer (score 2):

Scan out each 'token' from the list and use it as the basis for emitting source code that is a data step assignment statement:

```
%macro tweakOf(vars=);
  %local index var;
  %do index = 1 to %sysfunc(countw(&vars));
    %let var = %scan(&vars,&index);
    &var._new = &var + 2;  /* emit data step assignment statement */
  %end;
%mend;

data want;
  set have;
  %tweakOf(vars=a b c)
run;
```